# memory_limit override isn't causing an error when I expected

Tags: php

I'm creating a script that needs to exit when it hits a certain amount of memory usage. Here's my test script:

```
<?php

$memory_sapper = array();
$i = 0;

while (True){
    array_push($memory_sapper, $i);
    print($i);
    print(PHP_EOL);
    print((memory_get_usage()/1024)/1024 . " Mb");
    print(PHP_EOL);
    print(memory_get_usage() . " bytes");
    print(PHP_EOL);
    if ($i == 10000){
        print("Memory Limit: " . ini_get('memory_limit'));
        print(PHP_EOL);
        exit;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

When I run `php -d memory_limit=0.5M test.php`, memory usage starts at 0.3M and grows to 0.8M. I expected the script to error around `$i == 5000` but it's not, it goes past the memory limit of 0.5M.

`print("Memory Limit: " . ini_get('memory_limit'));` in the script shows that the memory limit is set to 0.5M.

Even `php -d memory_limit=0 test.php` doesn't keep the script from running.

If I increase `$i` to 100k, the script finally errors at 1.38 Mb or 1447328 bytes according to `memory_get_usage`. I'm unsure why it does't error sooner. Also, the number of bytes according to `memory_get_usage` isn't very close to the number of bytes recorded in the error. Here's the error message:

`PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 2097152 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 2097160 bytes) in ~/test.php on line 7`

Any insights would be valuable. Thank you!

Comment: Update: The bytes in the error match the bytes in `memory_get_usage` when the `$real_usage = True` is added: `memory_get_usage($real_usage = True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"0.5M" is not a valid value for `memory_limit`. If you look up [`memory_limit` in the PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit), it links to [this FAQ about the shorthand notation it accepts](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.using.php#faq.using.shorthandbytes), which  gives exactly that example:

> Note that the numeric value is cast to int; for instance, 0.5M is interpreted as 0.

So to set to "half a megabyte", you need to specify it in a whole number of kilobytes or bytes: `memory_limit=500k` or `memory_limit=512000`

Comment: Ah, thank you @IMSoP ! However, running `php -d memory_limit=500k  test.php` doesn't change the point at which the script exits. When I use that command, I get the same error message: `PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 2097152 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 2097160 bytes) in ~/test.php on line 7`

Comment: @trouble_bucket Hm, beyond my expertise, but I _suspect_ there's some minimum sized block of memory that PHP allocates, so that a limit below that just means "one block".

Comment: You're suspicion was accurate. I had to set the limit above the value of one block so it wouldn't scale to two blocks. Thanks so much!